# Frame of view don't resize when device change (using xib for iPhone 5)

Tags: ios, xib, iphone-6

Hello i have a xib for iPhone5, without using autolayout, size class. 
But when i want to adapt this screen to iphone 6 and 6+, 
the frame width never resize.
here is my solution, but it doesn't work.

```
 -(void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationBounds]];
}
```

Comment: Why do you not adjust the existing views frame or, if not using auto layout, use the springs and struts to make the view fill the screen automatically? Have you logged the bounds to confirm they are what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Launch images for the iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus devices? This method will return actual bounds values only if the Launch images are specified. You can add launch images using asset catalogs in Xcode.

Comment: i have launch image for iphone 6, in fact other screen works fine.

Comment: Are you sure you have launch images for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus? How did you add them ?